# Central quotient of $G=K\rtimes H$ where $H$ is core-free and $Z(G)\leqslant K$

Tags: group-theory, group-extensions

If $G=K\rtimes H$ is a semidiect product of a core-free group $H$ and a normal subgroup $K$ such that $Z(G)\leqslant K$, what can we conclude about the quotient $G/Z(G)$?

Comment: What does "core free subgroup" mean here? That the core of $\;H\;$ is the trivial subgroup?

Comment: There is no restriction so far. Take any group $G$. It is the semidirect product of $H=1$ and $K=G$ and $Z \leq K$.

Comment: Perhaps he meant to restrict $G$ to be a $p$-group, $H$ to be order $p$, $Z$ to be order $p$, but $G$ is not metacyclic. Then he may have meant to ask if $G/Z$ could be isomorphic to $K$. Mind-reading is tricky business, though, especially over the internet, so perhaps he should clarify the question.

Comment: can we say that $G \cong (K/Z(G)) \rtimes H$?

Comment: Those groups don't have the same order if $G$ is finite and $Z(G) \neq 1$, so no.